# How do I make a label for a slider that slides along with the current value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a label on top of the slider that moves along with it and updates it's value as it moves.
I can get the label to show but I don't know how to move it with the slider.

Also, I want to make buttons on the sides but if I place them on top of the bar, the slider doesn't work anymore. (code commented out)

```
function slideBar({ min, max, onChange, value, style, onCLick }) {

    return (
        <div className="slider-whole">
            <div className="labels" style={style}>                
                <p className="min">{min}</p>
                <p className="currentValue" style={style}>{value}</p>      
                <p className="max">{max}+</p>
            </div>

            <input
                type="range"
                name="range"
                min={min}
                max={max}git 
                value={value}
                className={`slider slider${style.color}`}
                id="myRange"
                onChange={onChange}
                style={style}
             />

            {/* <div className="arrow-buttons" style={style}>
            <i className="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
            <i className="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div> */}


            {/* <output htmlFor="range" onforminput="value = range.valueAsNumber;"></output> */}

            </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your class `slider-name` with `position:relative` and class `currentValue` with `position:absolute;` and set the value for `left` dynamically as the current value changes.